# How to add property to Transform category in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Is there any way to introduce a property to the Transform category of an object?
For this piece of code:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Transform")
bool myVar= true;
```

The Unreal property editor creates new Transform tab, instead of appending it to the existing Transform tab, [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfngL.png)

Is there any way to include this variable in the default Transform tab?

Comment: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Slate/DetailsCustomization/

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your blueprint and open the class defaults tab you will see the transform tab you created, the transform tab you see in the level only exists in the level. You could edit the engine definition of that tab for objects in your level but it might just be best that you left it alone.

**TL;DR:** No you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **FComponentTransformDetails**. This is where the "Transform" category is created.
You can create something like this class and add custom builder in editor customization.